Displacement variable not updating during test in Arduino project
I'm working on a project using Arduino to control a test machine for compression/tension. The displacement is calculated based on pulses from a sensor connected to a digital input. The logic for calculating the displacement works perfectly when the test is not active, but as soon as the test starts, the displacement value freezes at 0 and does not update.
Here is the simplified loop code:
cpp
Copy code
void loop() {
  // Verifica comandos recebidos via Serial
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();

    if (command == "C") {
      calibrateScale();
    } else if (command == "N") {
      resetCalibration();
    } else if (command == "IC") {
      contagemRegressiva();
      x = 0;               // Reseta o contador
      displacement = 0;    // Reseta o deslocamento
      ensaioAtivo = true;  // Inicia o ensaio
      TEnsaio = "COMPRESSAO...";
    } else if (command == "IT") {
      contagemRegressiva();
      x = 0;               // Reseta o contador
      displacement = 0;    // Reseta o deslocamento
      ensaioAtivo = true;  // Inicia o ensaio
      TEnsaio = "TRACAO...";
    } else if (command == "P") {
      pararMotor();
      ensaioAtivo = false;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("STOP S.O.S");
    }
  }

  // Atualiza deslocamento independentemente do ensaio
  if (digitalRead(input) == HIGH && state == 0) {
    state = 1;              // Define o estado para 1
    x = x + 1;              // Incrementa o contador de pulsos
    displacement = x * 2;   // Calcula o deslocamento
  }

  if (digitalRead(input) == LOW) {
    state = 0; // Redefine o estado
  }

  // Lógica do ensaio ativo
  if (ensaioAtivo) {
    float cargaAtual = abs(scale.get_units());

    if (cargaAtual >= MAX_LOAD) {
      ensaioAtivo = false;
      pararMotor();
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("CARGA MAX");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("P:");
      lcd.print(cargaAtual, 2);
      lcd.print("N");
    } else if (ultimaCarga > 2 && (ultimaCarga - cargaAtual) / ultimaCarga >= LOAD_DROP_THRESHOLD) {
      ensaioAtivo = false;
      pararMotor();
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("RUPTURA OK!");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("P:");
      lcd.print(ultimaCarga, 2);
      lcd.print("N");
    } else {
      // Exibe informações do ensaio durante a execução
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(TEnsaio);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("d:");
      lcd.print(displacement, 0);  // Exibe deslocamento
      lcd.print("mm  ");
      lcd.print("P:");
      lcd.print(cargaAtual, 2);
      lcd.print("N");
    }

    ultimaCarga = cargaAtual;
    delay(200);
  }

  // Exibe deslocamento no monitor Serial
  Serial.print("Deslocamento: ");
  Serial.print(displacement);
  Serial.println(" mm");
}


My guess would be an electrical problem not a code problem
